# jquery to show hidden text when an option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hide, show

```
  <form method="get" action="processform.php">
  <b>SELECT SERVICE</b><select name="Service">
  <option value="">Select a Service</option>
  <option value="toairport">To Airport</option>
  <option value="fromairport">From Airport</option>
  <option value="DriveAround">Drive Around</option>
  <option value="PointToPoint">Point TO Point</option>
  <option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
  <option value="Prom">Prom</option>
  <option value="Graduation">Graduation</option>
  <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
  <option value="Concert">Concert</option>
  <option value="SportingEvents">Sporting Events</option>
  <option value="Anniversary">Anniversary</option>
  </select>

   Airports<select name="airports">
  <option value="">Select an Airport</option>
  <option value="LGA">LaGuardia</option>
  <option value="JFK">Jonh F. Kennedy</option>
  <option value="Westchester">Westchester</option>
  <option value="Terteboro">Terteboro</option>
  <option value="Islip">Islip</option>
  </select>
```

I have the above code, In the service section when i click "from airport or to airport i wan the Airport option to show.
thanks in advance

Comment: I have the above code, In the service section when i click "from airport or to airport" I want the Airport's drop down menu to show. I did it through a text but i cannot do it while "from airport & to airport" is inside a service selection menu as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('select[name="Service"]').change(function(){
    var v = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('select[name="airports"]').toggle((v == 'toairport' || v == 'fromairport'));
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u3aqW/).

You could also use a simple regular expression to test that the `value` ends with the word `airport` (which matches the requirements as posted, in that both options for which you're testing end with the string 'airport'):

```
$('select[name="Service"]').change(function(){
    var v = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('select[name="airports"]').toggle(v.match(/airport$/));
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u3aqW/1/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp).
- [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Wow! that's nice +1. I din't know this technique. Nice!

Comment: Thank you very much, the first script works much better, the second one works but it displays the aiport menu regardless what i click..

Comment: Really? May I ask what browser you were using to try the latter alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("select[name=Service]").change(function(e){
    if(e.target.value == "toairport" || e.target.value == "fromairport"){
        $("select[name=airports]").show();
    }else{
        $("select[name=airports]").hide();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this:

```
$("#airports").hide()
$("#service").change(function(){
    if(this.value == 'toairport' || this.value == 'fromairport')
       $("#airports").show();
    else
        $("#airports").hide();
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<select name="Service" id="service">
<select name="airports" id="airports">
```

**DEMO** --> http://jsfiddle.net/jA56n/